# Can TortoiseSVN commit window receive parameters?

Tags: tortoisesvn, hook

I wrote a start-commit hook that will return (when exited), a number.

Is it possible that the return value will be automatically inserted to the commit BugId value? or the message body itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To insert something in the commit dialog (message body and/or bugid value), implement an [IBugtraqProvider](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-ibugtraqprovider.html) plugin.

Comment: I'm working with SalesForce as my Issue Tracker. Can I inmplement IBugtraqProvider ?

Comment: Implementing an IBugtraqProvider has nothing to do with the issue tracker you're using. The interface doesn't know which issue tracker you're using - it's up to you to implement the connection to it.

Comment: I've read about IBugtraq. What kind of connection to my issue tracker? does it connects to a database and retrieves data from there?